# Attaching video doorbell to stucco over rigid foam insulation

Tags: mounting, anchor, stucco

To the right and left of my front door are 6" deep protrusions/doorposts covered in stucco. I'm pretty sure (from another home installation project) that these posts are not really doorposts but are stucco over rigid foam insulation.

I want to mount a video doorbell (weight less than a pound) to this area next to my front door.  I have bits that are diamond tip rated to go thru the stucco. I can even get a hammer drill if needed.

My concern is ***how to get the two anchors to hold*** if there is nothing behind the stucco other than rigid foam insulation.

The frame for the doorbell is what is actually mounted and holds the doorbell which needs to be periodically removed for charging.  So, the mounting frame for the doorbell will be jiggled and wiggled somewhat as the doorbell is removed for charging and then re-attached.  My concern is the anchors will loosen or never hold to begin with.

I have thought of drilling the holes (6mm drill bit recommended by product)
and then filling the hole with caulking or hot-glue before inserting the anchors .  Have no idea if this would work.

What's the best way to deal with this job?

Comment: To aid your searches, that stucco-over-foam is most commonly referred to as "EIFS" (Exterior Insulation and Finishing System).

Answer (score 1):

It would be important to find out if the entire column is rigid foam, or if it has a wood/steel/concrete/plastic core. If it has a core, you can use whatever type of fastener is ideal for that material (and long enough to penetrate the foam layer).

If it is truly rigid foam all the way through, you might consider drilling a hole and then using a [molly fastener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molly_(fastener)) which when engaged would push hard outward from the hole against the rigid foam. Some kind of slow-drying glue or epoxy may help enhance that effect.

Otherwise, you're probably looking at some other kind of preparation. If you can engage a block of wood large enough (2x4 or 1x4) to mount the doorbell bracket, you may be able to embed it with glue and repair the stucco around it so it looks somewhat natural.

Comment: I'm thinking that the only way to determine what the core is - is to drill a pilot hole of some sort.  Maybe in an area that will eventually be behind the bracket. would that be your approach for determining the core?

Comment: @user163862 Yes, that ought to work.

Comment: I would think a molly bolt would very likely cause cracks in the surface spreading out from that point.  What I'd do instead is drill a bit bigger hole, glue a wooden dowel into it, and screw into that (or preferably all the way through that, into the sheathing behind.)

Comment: I ended up doing what @NateS. suggested, using 3.5" screws to get through the foam to the plywood sheathing behind. To determine how thick your rigid foam is, what you can do is puncture the stucco with a small drill bit, then use a long thin nail to push through to the sheathing, mark that depth on the nail (or keep your fingers there) then measure the depth after you've pulled the nail out. Mine was 2", so a 3.5" screw was definitely enough to get through the doorbell backing, the foam and fully embed in the plywood. No anchors used in this case.